# How to iterate through each model within a array in an Angular Component?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post

I need to call a web service with inputs and a POST. The service would return an JSON array of objects. I wanted to collect these into an Angular Arrya of Objects and display them on the page.

Instead of the actual values of the objects, the key/values of "Subscribe" is printing. the `val` in `http.post` prints correct values. But not sure if and array of `Azureblob` are being created with `return this.http.post<Azureblob[]>(this.serverUrl...` ?

Appreciate any help in this.

[image]

**model**

```
export class Azureblob {
  blobName: string;
  blobURL: string;
  blboMimeType: string;
}
```

**service**

```
getAllBlobs() {
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept' : 'application/json'
});

return this.http.post<Azureblob[]>(this.serverUrl,
  JSON.stringify({
    "acountName": "abc",
    "acountKey": "def",
    "container":"ghi",
  }),{headers: headers}).subscribe(
  (val) => {
    console.log("POST call successful value returned in body",
      val);
  },
  response => {
    console.log("POST call in error", response);
  },
  () => {
    console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
  });
}
```

**pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'keys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: {}): string[] {
     if (!value) {
       return [];
     }
     return Object.keys(value);
   }
}
```

**component**

```
blobsList : any;
constructor(private azureblobService : AzureblobService) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllBlobs();
}

getAllBlobs() : void {
  this.blobsList = this.azureblobService.getAllBlobs();
}
```

**component html**

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let key of blobsList | keys">
      {{key}}
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code seems to returns observable. You should write `subscribe` operator in component not in service.

**In Service:**

```
getAllBlobs() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept' : 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.post<Azureblob[]>(this.serverUrl,
      JSON.stringify({
        "acountName": "abc",
        "acountKey": "def",
        "container":"ghi",
      }),{headers: headers});
}
```

**In Component:**

```
blobsList : any;
constructor(private azureblobService : AzureblobService) { }
ngOnInit() {
   this.getAllBlobs();
}

getAllBlobs() : void {
  this.azureblobService.getAllBlobs()
  .subscribe(
      (val) => {
        console.log("POST call successful value returned in body",
          val);
        this.blobsList = val; //<====== Set value here
      },
      response => {
        console.log("POST call in error", response);
      },
      () => {
        console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
      });
}
```